# how to sort in ascending order all columns of a data frame in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 348 numeric columns and I would like to put all these columns in ascending order.
How to do this?
I tried some codes that sorted the first column in ascending order. I want them all in ascending order.
Exemple:

```
a1 = runif(n = 50, min = 0.1, max = 120)
a2 = runif(n = 50, min = 5, max = 151)
a3 = runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 100)
a4 = runif(n = 50, min = 6, max = 180)
a5 = runif(n = 50, min = 6, max = 183)
a6 = runif(n = 50, min = 6, max = 254)

df = data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
df

df2 = df[with(df, order(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)), ]
head(df2)
```

df2 with the first column in ascending order but I want them all (a1:a6 in ascending order)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), sort))

# A tibble: 50 x 6
      a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    a6
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2.30  5.31  3.28  8.25  8.62  11.2
 2  3.39 15.6   3.70 16.4  21.0   12.7
 3  7.11 24.3   8.29 17.9  22.1   17.4
 4 10.8  24.3   9.09 25.3  25.8   22.0
 5 11.9  40.2   9.86 25.4  28.7   24.3
 6 13.7  40.6  11.3  25.7  31.3   37.1
 7 21.4  41.6  12.3  29.6  39.1   38.1
 8 27.1  56.3  12.8  39.3  40.5   45.5
 9 28.7  60.1  14.3  39.8  46.2   63.8
10 29.1  62.1  15.4  50.2  46.8   72.8
# ... with 40 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` should be fast:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, names(df) := lapply(.SD, sort)]
head(df)
          a1        a2        a3       a4       a5        a6
1: 0.1877075  6.731233  1.354166 12.82542 15.43206  8.385348
2: 0.3087580 14.567764  7.271257 14.18342 18.84559 20.998163
3: 1.3518180 15.943932  8.163164 15.69317 20.46418 28.797276
4: 6.9881726 19.086500 11.085330 18.38545 29.16079 30.808385
5: 7.5015324 19.158892 12.257267 18.86634 32.27948 32.997170
6: 7.6574802 21.143694 14.037592 20.07155 37.85144 49.052889
```

Note that this is updating *by reference*, and so there is no need to write something like `df <- df %>% ...` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sapply` + `sort`. Using `order` on multiple columns, you will not be able to change the row positions of the columns independently, i.e. you'll get an order of priority for columns to be sorted.

```r
sapply(df, sort)
```